# Calling an external function with GetProcAddress crashes the app

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to call an external function with the GetProcAddress function but everytime i  call the function it crashes the console, ive been looking but in every post i get the same final solution but when i try it in my DLL it crashes the app.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "SDK\plugin.h"

typedef void (*logprintf_t)(char* format, ...);
logprintf_t logprintf;
// static void* m_AMXExports[44];

typedef bool (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginLoad_t)(void **data);
typedef void (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginUnload_t)();
typedef unsigned int (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginSupports_t)();
typedef void (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginProcessTick_t)();

typedef int (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginAmxLoad_t)(AMX *amx);
typedef int (PLUGIN_CALL *ServerPluginAmxUnload_t)(AMX *amx);

struct Plugins
{
    void* AppData[256];
    SUPPORTS_FLAGS FlagSupport;
    HMODULE Module;
    ServerPluginLoad_t      LOAD;
    ServerPluginUnload_t    UNLOAD;
    ServerPluginSupports_t  SUPPORTS;
    ServerPluginProcessTick_t   PROCESSTICK;

    // AMX Plugin Interface
    ServerPluginAmxLoad_t   AMXLOAD;
    ServerPluginAmxUnload_t AMXUNLOAD;
};
Plugins* ServerPlugins;

void **ppPluginData ;

extern void *pAMXFunctions;

//native LoadLibrary(libraryname[]);
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL my_LoadLibrary(AMX* amx, cell* params)
{
    bool validfunc = false;
    char *path;
    amx_StrParam(amx, params[1], path);
    logprintf("Loading plugin %s", path);
    ServerPlugins = new Plugins();
    ServerPlugins->Module = LoadLibraryA(path);
    if (ServerPlugins->Module == NULL)
    {
        delete ServerPlugins;
        logprintf("Failed loading plugin %s (Error: %d)", path, GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }
    logprintf("NULL");
    ServerPlugins->LOAD = (ServerPluginLoad_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "Load");
    ServerPlugins->UNLOAD = (ServerPluginUnload_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "Unload");
    ServerPlugins->SUPPORTS = (ServerPluginSupports_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "Supports");
    if (ServerPlugins->LOAD == NULL || ServerPlugins->SUPPORTS == NULL || ServerPlugins->UNLOAD == NULL)
    {
        logprintf(" Plugin doesnt conform to architecture");
        FreeLibrary(ServerPlugins->Module);
        delete ServerPlugins;
        return false;
    }
    logprintf("NULL 1");
    ServerPlugins->FlagSupport = (SUPPORTS_FLAGS)ServerPlugins->SUPPORTS();
    if ((ServerPlugins->FlagSupport & SUPPORTS_VERSION_MASK) > SUPPORTS_VERSION)
    {
        logprintf("Unsupported Version; unloading.");
        FreeLibrary(ServerPlugins->Module);
        delete ServerPlugins;
        return false;
    }
    logprintf("NULL 2");
    if ((ServerPlugins->FlagSupport & SUPPORTS_AMX_NATIVES) > SUPPORTS_VERSION)
    {
        ServerPlugins->AMXLOAD = (ServerPluginAmxLoad_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "AmxLoad");
        ServerPlugins->AMXUNLOAD = (ServerPluginAmxUnload_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "AmxUnload");
    }
    else
    {
        ServerPlugins->AMXLOAD = NULL;
        ServerPlugins->AMXUNLOAD = NULL;
        logprintf("Any Abstract Machine has been loaded");
    }
    logprintf("NULL 3");
    if ((ServerPlugins->FlagSupport & SUPPORTS_PROCESS_TICK) != 0)
    {
        ServerPlugins->PROCESSTICK = (ServerPluginProcessTick_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "ProcessTick");
    }
    else
    {
        ServerPlugins->PROCESSTICK = NULL;
    }
    logprintf("NULL 4"); //debugging
    ServerPlugins->AppData[PLUGIN_DATA_AMX_EXPORTS] = pAMXFunctions;
    ServerPlugins->AppData[PLUGIN_DATA_LOGPRINTF] = &logprintf;
    if (!(ServerPlugins->LOAD)(ServerPlugins->AppData)) //i didnt put it as &ServerPlugins->AppData because it causes an error
    {

        logprintf("Initialized failed loading plugin %s", path);
        FreeLibrary(ServerPlugins->Module);
        logprintf("NULL 5");
        delete ServerPlugins;
        return false;
    }
    logprintf("Plugin %s loaded", path);
    return true;
}
//native UnloadLibrary(libraryname[]);
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL my_UnloadLibrary(AMX*amx, cell*params)
{
    char *path;
    amx_StrParam(amx, params[1], path);
    ServerPlugins->Module = GetModuleHandle((LPCTSTR)path);
    if (ServerPlugins->Module != NULL)
    {
        ServerPlugins->UNLOAD = (ServerPluginUnload_t)GetProcAddress(ServerPlugins->Module, "Unload");
        if (ServerPlugins->UNLOAD != NULL)
        {
            ServerPlugins->UNLOAD();
            FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandleA(path));
            logprintf("Library %s has been unloaded correctly", path);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            logprintf("Unloading library %s failed (Error: %d)", GetLastError());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL Load(void **ppData)
{
    pAMXFunctions = ppData[PLUGIN_DATA_AMX_EXPORTS];
    logprintf = (logprintf_t)ppData[PLUGIN_DATA_LOGPRINTF];
    return 1;
}

PLUGIN_EXPORT void PLUGIN_CALL Unload()
{
}

PLUGIN_EXPORT unsigned int PLUGIN_CALL Supports()
{
    return SUPPORTS_VERSION | SUPPORTS_AMX_NATIVES;
}

AMX_NATIVE_INFO projectNatives[] =
{
    { "LoadLibrary", my_LoadLibrary },
    { "UnloadLibrary", my_UnloadLibrary }
};

PLUGIN_EXPORT int PLUGIN_CALL AmxLoad(AMX *amx)
{
    return amx_Register(amx, projectNatives, -1);
}

PLUGIN_EXPORT int PLUGIN_CALL AmxUnload(AMX *amx)
{
    return AMX_ERR_NONE;
}
```

Comment: How do we know that you declared the params correctly?

Comment: And what is `ppData`? I assume it's a pointer? Have it been properly allocated? Do you perform proper error handling inside the loaded code? Do you perhaps have an uninitialized local variable in the called function? Or a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: Sorry I missed the declaration of Load in the other plugin and the declaration of ppData.

Comment: I smell [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere in the use of an array of pointer to `void` and its use as a pointer to pointer to `void`. I don't think it *should* matter as the memory layout should actually be the same, but it still looks "fishy" to me. And if you have "function pointers" at fixed positions in the array, why not just use a structure of function pointers for that too?

Comment: I dont get your advise, would you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory leak in `convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR()`.  You are never freeing the `wchar_t*` that you allocate.  The `convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR()` function itself is not needed, you can simply pass the `char*` path as-is to `LoadLibraryA()` instead:

```
char *path;
amx_StrParam(amx, params[1], path);
...
ServerPlugins->Module = LoadLibraryA(path);
```

You are not checking if `ServerPlugins->UNLOAD` is successfully loaded by `GetProcAddress("Unload")` or not.

You are using `GetProcAddress("Load")` for both `ServerPlugins->LOAD` and `ServerPlugins->AMXLOAD`, and `GetProcAddress("Unload")` for both `ServerPlugins->UNLOAD` and `ServerPlugins->AMXUNLOAD`.  That is very fishy to me.  Does the DLL really use the same exports for AMX and non-AMX entry points?  If so, that is very bad design, considering that `ServerPluginLoad_t` has a very different signature than `ServerPluginAmxLoad_t`, and the same for `ServerPlugin(Amx)Unload_t`.  That is a corrupted call stack waiting to happen.  It would be much safer to have the DLL export separate `AmxLoad()` and `AmxUnload()` functions instead.

For that matter, the `SUPPORTS_AMX_NATIVES` and `SUPPORTS_PROCESS_TICK` flags are redundant, since `GetProcAddress()` would tell you if those exports are available or not.

As for the crash when calling `ServerPlugins->LOAD`, I do not see you initializing `ppData` with any data before passing it to `Load()`.  Certainly not the `PLUGIN_DATA_AMX_EXPORTS` and `PLUGIN_DATA_LOGPRINTF` slots, at least:

```
ppData[PLUGIN_DATA_AMX_EXPORTS] = pAMXFunctions;
ppData[PLUGIN_DATA_LOGPRINTF] = &logprintf;
if (!(ServerPlugins->LOAD)(ppData))
```

So even if the call to `Load()` itself did not crash, the DLL would still likely crash at a later time when it tries to use its local `pAMXFunctions` and `logprintf` pointers that were assigned in `Load()`.

For that matter, why are you passing things like that as a `void*` array instead of a `struct`?  That would have been much safer, eg:

```
struct PluginInitData
{
    void* pAMXFunctions;
    logprintf_t logprintf;
    ...
};

typedef bool (__stdcall *ServerPluginLoad_t)(PluginInitData* data);

PluginInitData pInitData;
pInitData.pAMXFunctions = pAMXFunctions;
pInitData.logprintf = &logprintf;
...
if (!(ServerPlugins->LOAD)(&pInitData))
```

```
extern "C" bool __stdcall Load(PluginInitData* data)
{
    pAMXFunctions = data->pAMXFunctions;
    logprintf = data->logprintf;
    ...
    return true;
}
```

**Update**: you have fixed most of the issues I mentioned, but now I see that your `my_UnloadLibrary()` function is implemented wrong.  **DO NOT** call `GetModuleHandle()` or `GetProcAddress()` at all, use the existing `Module` and `UNLOAD` pointers that were initialized earlier in `my_LoadLibrary()`.

```
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL my_LoadLibrary(AMX* amx, cell* params)
{
    char *path;
    amx_StrParam(amx, params[1], path);
    ...
    ServerPlugins->Path = path;
    ...
}

static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL my_UnloadLibrary(AMX*amx, cell*params)
{
    if (ServerPlugins)
    {
        if (ServerPlugins->UNLOAD != NULL)
            ServerPlugins->UNLOAD();

        if (ServerPlugins->Module != NULL)
        {
            FreeLibrary(ServerPlugins->Module);
            ServerPlugins->Module = NULL;
        }

        logprintf("Library %s has been unloaded", ServerPlugins->Path);

        delete ServerPlugins;
        ServerPlugins = NULL;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

If you are still having problems with `Load()` crashing, then you are just going to have to use your compiler's debugger to find out what is actually happening at run-time.  The code shown so far should not be crashing, so either you have a calling convention mismatch, or a data alignment mismatch, or corrupted memory, or something like that.  We can't run you debugger for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i realize that i was doing something that doesnt make any sense at all (the amxload and that) but it keeps  crashing when i get to the ServerPlugins->LOAD i edited the main post with the new code

Comment: I ran de debugger and it says that there is an access violation error, i checked on the MSDN and it says that this is caused because the parameters of the function arent correct. It makes no sense http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx